# UPDATE and DELETE in same SQL in multiple tables?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

With Oracle DB, is it possible to update one table and delete (matching rows) in other?

I tried various forms of `MERGE` but I get either:

> ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.

(probably caused by `UNION ALL` in the view)

or

> ORA-38106: MERGE not supported on join view or view with INSTEAD OF trigger.

This ("join view") suggests that specifying two tables in any form is a no-go for `MERGE`. Is that correct?

(the reasons for using a single statement are: performance, consistency and clarity)

My Oracle DB is of version 11.2.

The actual problem is like this:

We (a library) have a (parent) table of *books* and a (child) table of *content* (one or zero per book, it has a FK to the *books* table). Every year we run a job that for each book that is older than 10 years (let's simplify the condition as it is not relevant to the problem here) we set a column named RETIRED to value "YES" in the *books* table and delete the row (if present) in the *content* table.

PS: PL/SQL solutions are welcome. (my code is in PL/SQL anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Use **one** transaction with two statements:

1. Update `books` to retire;
2. Delete `content` of all the retired books.

PL/SQL solution might be:

```
DECLARE
 TYPE id_list IS TABLE OF books.id%TYPE;
 retired_list id_list;
BEGIN
  UPDATE books
  SET retired = 'YES'
  WHERE publish_date <= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -120)
  RETURNING id BULK COLLECT INTO retired_list;

  FORALL id IN retired_list.FIRST .. retired_list.LAST
    DELETE content
    WHERE book_id = retired_list(id);

  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Comment: That will make two scans of the `books` table (performance) and if the delete is done as `DELETE ... where BOOKS.RETIRED='YES'` it will try to delete already deleted (in previous years) contents (again: performance).

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use `RETURNING ... BULK COLLECT INTO ...` to store only updated book ids in a collection and apply `FORALL` to delete `content` by these ids only. Admittedly, that would be PL\SQL solution, not SQL.

Comment: Is there any advantage in using `FORALL` instead of `DELETE from content WHERE book_id = IN (select value(x) from TABLE(retired_list) x);` ?

Comment: I would ask this question on [DBA StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). There are context switching between PL/SQL and SQL, moving data from PGA to SGA, potential parallel processing and all sorts of wonderful stuff to consider.

Comment: [FORALL vs TABLE()](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2445448?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Even more efficient and bullet-proof way might actually be to create a trigger on `books` for update when `retired` gets updated to 'YES' that would take care of the `content`.